# Error message in installing github projects

Tags: r, error-handling, installation, gitlab

I am trying to install the ggmap latest version package from github using

`devtools::install_git`("dkahle/ggmap") and it shows me this error. Can anyone help me out? 
Thank you

```
Downloading git repo dkahle/ggmap
Error in git2r::clone(x$url, bundle, credentials = x$credentials, progress = FALSE) : 
  Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol
In addition: Warning message:
In git2r::remote_ls(remote$url, credentials = remote$credentials) :
  Error in 'git2r_remote_ls': unsupported URL protocol
```

Comment: It should be `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap") `. Not `install_git`

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question, but for some reason it is still showing me an error message:


Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pkgload', details:
  call: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
  error: there is no package called ‘backports’

Comment: Then install the package backports. `install.packages('backports')` and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Finally, I was able to install the latest version of ggmap